# How to call original method in btakita/rr ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rr

I need to check that particular method is called. Is it possible in btakita/rr?

rspec example from:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method!

```
    Addition.should_receive(:two_plus_two).and_call_original
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [original rr announcement](http://pivotallabs.com/introducing-rr/), you'd need to use the following approach:

```
original_two_plus_two = Addition.method(:two_plus_two)
mock(Addition).two_plus_two {original_two_plus_two.call}
```

However, if you'd be ok with the double being called *after* the original, then you can use rr's *proxy* feature, described at https://github.com/rr/rr#proxies, as follows:

```
mock.proxy(Addition).two_plus_two
```

(Nod to @ElliotWinkler for clarifying that no block is required in this case.)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. :-)  As an experiment, I'm making this comment on my ten most recent accepted-without-an-upvote answers and providing the link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting to see what the response is. Note that I fully respect everyone's right to upvote, downvote or do neither as they see fit. :-)

Comment: You don't need the block. Just use `mock.proxy(Addition).two_plus_two`.

Comment: @ElliotWinkler Thanks. I believe you and I'll update my answer, but if you happen to know if this is documented anywhere else but the code, I'd appreciate a reference.

Comment: I moved the repo to http://github.com/rr/rr. There's a section on proxies [here](https://github.com/rr/rr#proxies) and also some more information about it [here](https://github.com/rr/rr/blob/master/doc/03_api_overview.md#mockproxy) (although it doesn't really explain proxies very well, I need to do an overhaul of this document). EDIT: Oh you were talking about that #proxy doesn't have to take a block. No unfortunately that is not documented, I just happen to know that.